# Expand/Collapse TableRow component in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, tablerow, material-ui

I need to expand the TableRow component to open another div containing some fields. But **React** throws a warning if I try to add divs in the table body.

```
warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr>. See RowComponent > TableRow > tr > div.
```

Required functionality is similar to `^` button from the nested list component to collapse / expand.
Is there any way to customize the **material-ui TableRow** to expand/collapse ?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables

Answer (score 10):

The material-ui site table component page has an example of a "Collapsible table": https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table.

That example is exactly what I was looking for, and I'm sure many others as well.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your use-case you may want to use [expansion panels](https://material-ui.com/demos/expansion-panels/) instead.

If you still want to use a table, you can set the `component` prop on the [`Collapse`](https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/) component. You'll have to use this outside of your original `TableRow`. Inside of a `TableCell` or `td`, you can use any element you want. Check out [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0yox54302n) for a working example.

The interesting snippet:

```js
<Collapse in={open} component="tr" style={{ display: "block" }}>
  <td>
    <div>Expanded data.</div>
  </td>
</Collapse>
```

The important parts here:

1. `component="tr"` tells the `Collapse`  component to use a `tr` instead of a `div`
2. `display: "block"` to overwrite the default `display: "table-row"` of the `tr` component

Comment: Are there solution to avoid divs within <tr>? <tr><div><td/></div> ?

Comment: This suggestion still throws the warning

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <div>`

Answer (score 4):

This solution works, you can also add `colSpan` to the `TableCell` that contains the `Collapse` to match the border width with the number of TableCells at the top.

```
function ExpandingRow({ summary, details }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <TableRow hover onClick={() => { setOpen(!open) }}>
        <TableCell>
          {summary}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow>
        <TableCell style={{ padding: 0 }}>
          <Collapse in={open}>{details}</Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` is not supported inside a TableRow. Removing the `<div>` tag and using a `Card` component in its place worked for me.

You can see the code here : https://github.com/shiveeg1/tracker-quick-entry/blob/master/src/components/super-row.js

Also there are multiple alternatives provided on this thread which were very helpful: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/4476